# Filter maven resources with filter-file from external dependency

Tags: maven-2

Given a property file in maven project A

I want to use them in project B for resource filtering.

So in Project B I use

```
<build>
        <filters>
            <filter>${project.build.directory}/myFile.properties</filter>
        </filters>
 </build>
```

To filter my resources based on values in myFile.properties This file is stored in project A. So I include it with

```
    <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>groupa</groupId>
                                <artifactId>a</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <type>test-jar</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Problem is that the resource filtering happens before the dependency is copied. So filtering does work when copying myFile.properties manually to ${project.build.directory} but it does not work with a mvn clean ...

How can I copy the filterFile before the actual filtering happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven plugins are executed in the order they appear in the pom. AFAIK the plugins configured in the parent (and the super pom) are executed before the plugins of the pom.

My suggestion is declaring the resources plugin explicitely after the dependency plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- ... -->
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- ... -->
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are right order is important. First the phase is considered and within the same phase the order of declaration. Before mvn 3.0.3 order within same issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2258 was wrong. Sorry for my late reaction. Glade we have mvn 3 or gradle now :)